# Data extraction recommendation software (email, name, country)

Tags: data-mining, extract, data-extraction

I would like to extract some data from plain files (thunderbird mailboxes, html files, csv). I  usually get strings like this (into files)

user: pepito
phone: 11233213
email: user@domain.com

Then I am searching a software that lets me extract by string (scripts, macros, it) and export to CSV by separated columns,

Could you recommend me a software or way for doing it?
Your help will be very appreciated

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extracting I would recommend NLP grammar tools such as [GATE/JAPE](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf) or [GExp](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/).

Comment: thank you but I would like a standard software (I am not expert) Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by standard? GATE perhaps is most widely used soft for IE(it has GUI environment as well), it is defacto standard.

Comment: ok, I mean "easy". Sorry but I am not an expert, I will give it a try. Thank you!